# How to assign 'React Native Simple Store' value to a variable.?

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I've installed react-native-simple-store module in my app.

```
   var x=this.state.uname;
   store.save('user', x)
```

I'm storing a username as above and I can alert that stored object as :

```
store.get('user').then((res) => alert(res)
```

I can alert **res**. But how to store it in a variable.?

Comment: React is already provide the AsyncStorage, use this one. https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/asyncstorage.html

Comment: tried but failed...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assign it on the callback `.then()`:

```
let foo;

store.get('user').then((res) => {
  foo = res; //assign value to your variable foo from outside
  console.log(foo);
});
```

Here's an example assigning it to state:

```
constructor() {
   super();
   this.state = {
      foo: ""
   }
}

componentDidMount() {
   store.get('user').then((res) => {
      this.setState({foo: res}); //assign value to your variable
   });
}

render() {
   <Text>{this.state.foo}</Text>
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked. Can u tell me how to use this inside a <Text> tag?

Comment: My answer also includes an example how to use it with state that is being rendered on a `<Text>` Tag.

Comment: What do you mean use it inside the text tag? Can you show your code?

Comment: Same as u said. <Text>{this.state.foo}</Text>

Comment: Maybe there's nothing on the store? Or are you getting something from it? You can also try to `setState` statically just to try if it will update on the `render()`

Comment: You should never `setState` inside `render`, so the original answer is correct, though it's missing `return` statement from render.

Comment: Oops sorry, thank you for pointing it. You can maybe update it and I will approve it, or I'll update it?

Comment: its not working outside render(). but worked well inside render()